# Which Type combination still exist for which there are no pokemon?

Tags: pokemon

With the introduction of Fairy type, the total Types has increased to 18. This has increased number of possibly types (unique, i.e. Primary/Secondary is same as Secondary/Primary) to 171.

How many of such combinations have been used and which combinations are still left to be used i.e. No pokemon exist for such type?

Examples off the top of my head?
Bug/Dragon, Electric/Poison etc.
Unique Type used in Gen 6 - Water/Fire - Volcanion

Edit: Gen 7 Introduced. Thanks @Kenny980 for updating!

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking this on Arqade?

Comment: Possible. Types relate to both anime and games though. I'd leave it upto the mdos I guess?

Comment: I'm just saying there's much more activity and pokemon fans which might be more knowledgeable about these things than here. You could cross-post without deleting this question for better coverage.

Comment: The question is fine here, but I think it makes a lot more sense on Arqade, since this is a pretty game-mechanic-y question. I can migrate it if you'd like.

Comment: I just posted here because I am much more active here, and haven't added Arcade to my Stack. I have no idea how the cross post works thoguh.

Comment: Cross-posting without deletion is actually pretty discouraged here (= SE) @Hakase.

Comment: @Jan says who? You can't just discourage things without context.

Comment: @Hakase Says about every single other comment I have seen so far about cross-posting on SE sites.

Comment: Probably because it wasn't reasonable, but I'm not going to get into a discussion about it since we already have an answer here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following image shows the Pokemon types of which there are no Pokemon as of Gen 6:

[image: Pokemon Types with no Pokemon]

This information was sourced from: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_type_combinations_by_abundance

**--Update for Gen 7--**

New types that are available in Gen 7:

[image: New Gen 7 types]

Which leaves these types still with no Pokemon:

[image: Gen 7 Remaining types with no Pokemon]

Comment: no dark fairy?  no fighting ghost? some of these sound pretty badass

Comment: No Electric Fighting... Electiwire was a great candidate. Cross Chop/Brick Break with STAB!

Comment: In generation 7 pokemon games trailer introduce more unique combination, but the games and anime are not yet release :(

Comment: Update to accomodate the Gen 7?

Comment: Updated for Gen 7 :)

Comment: @Kenny890 Cheers.

Comment: @kaine Marshadow was released and it is a Fighting/Ghost Pokemon.

Comment: @FurioDeroria yeah, the answer was updated. But my comment proceeded that.